# MongoDB, how to filter based on previous record's date value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am not sure this is possible to achieve, I just want to be certain.

I have sorted dates records, for example:

```
{id: 1, date: 2015-08-18T00:00:00Z },
{id: 2, date: 2015-08-18T00:01:00Z },
{id: 3, date: 2015-08-18T00:02:00Z },
{id: 4, date: 2015-08-18T00:03:00Z },
{id: 5, date: 2015-08-18T00:04:00Z },
```

And I only want to get the records that are separated by at least 2 minutes.
record 2 would be invalid, because it is less than 2 minutes before record 1, but record 3 would be valid, so the result would be:

```
{id: 1, date: 2015-08-18T00:00:00Z },
{id: 3, date: 2015-08-18T00:02:00Z },
{id: 5, date: 2015-08-18T00:04:00Z },
```

I think the only way is to query them all, and do the filtering programmatically, but i am curious to know if there is an a pure mongoDB solution to this problem.

Comment: I suggest while storing the documents only you can flag them to be selected and query based on the flag. I am also curious if there is an aggregation pipeline which can solve this!! (Even if it is there it might not be that efficient)

Comment: I have a very large array containing sensor data points taken at every minute. All I want to do is display an overview of these sensor points in a graph and only need a sensor point every 30 minute to 1 hour! I'm very anxious to see if this is possible to do in Mongo... otherwise, I'll have to filter it once it's loaded into memory.